# Replace the two cases of invalid closing tags

Tags: regex

Please help me with this basic RegEx example.

There are two cases where the syntax is valid:

- @$ should be closed as $@ (and not @$);
- $@ should be closed as @$ (and not $@).

In order to replace the cases of invalid syntax usage with the right syntax *at a very large scale*, I first need to find those cases using regular expressions.

**The problem** appears when the wrong syntax is combined with the right syntax. Please, take a look at the following test on RegExr: https://regexr.com/548e8. I've also written it below:

**Expression** (should match the first case):

```
/@(.*)\$(.*)@(.*)\$/gsU
```

**Text**:

```
First case: @Correct $tags$ before@     @these $incorrect@ tags$
Second case: $Correct @tags@ before$     $these @incorrect$ tags@

The expression was written only for the first case.
```

It starts and the beggining of the first section ($@) and it ends at the beginning of the second section (where it finds "$@" again).

I also need the keep the sU flags.

Thank you!

Comment: Try `/@([^@$]*)\$([^@$]*)@([^@$]*)\$|\$([^@$]*)@([^@$]*)\$([^@$]*)@g/`, see https://regex101.com/r/4gBNCg/1

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response! It doesn't seem to work for the following example: https://regex101.com/r/4gBNCg/2. Can you please help me?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. You are testing against a single multiline string, so add `\n` to the character classes there. See https://regex101.com/r/4gBNCg/3

Comment: Thank you a lot! Can you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
/@([^@$]*)\$([^@$]*)@([^@$]*)\$|\$([^@$]*)@([^@$]*)\$([^@$]*)@g/
```

Or, to stay on the same line while matching, use

```
/@([^@$\n\r]*)\$([^@$\n\r]*)@([^@$\n\r]*)\$|\$([^@$\n\r]*)@([^@$\n\r]*)\$([^@$\n\r]*)@g/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4gBNCg/3)

Here, `[^@$\n\r]*` matches any 0+ occurrences of any char but `@`, `$`, CR and LF. The two alternatives are joined with an `|` OR operator.

Comment: Awesome pattern :-)